# How to access javascript variable within @URL.Action()

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can I access JavaScript value inside `@URL.Action()`?
something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function name(myjavascriptID)
{
     jQuery("#list_d").jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: '@URL.Action("download file", "download", new { id = <myjavascriptID> })', page: 1 });

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You can't.  JavaScript doesn't execute when generating the action URL.  What you can do, is do something like this:

```
function name(myjavascriptID)    {
     var link = '@Url.Action("download file", "download", new { id = "-1" })';
     link = link.replace("-1", myjavascriptID);

     jQuery("#list_d").jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: link, page: 1 });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works with one small modification: instead of `link.href` I need to use `link` . Thanks very much!

Comment: What if id will be string like "Hello world" ?

Comment: The idea is for the -1 to be something uniquely identifiable in the string, for you to replace with whatever you want.  You would need to make sure Hello World is encoded, like Hello+World.  But yes, replace it with whatever you want

Comment: is there no cleaner solution?

Comment: Great answer. Now I don't have to worry about changes in routing configuration. I use "{id}" string instead of "-1", so it looks more natural to me and I don't have to worry about using -1 value for any other variable in the future, but unfortunately in replace function it has to be converted by Url.Encode and also there's a difference in letters case in those strings.

Comment: remove capital URL prefixed before `@URL.Action`  to `@Url.Action` as it shows compile time error

Comment: Hadn't thought of this. It's a good shout as I would never have -1 as a valid Id, yet it's a valid int for my route. Only issue is if there 'is' a valid -1 elsewhere in the route. Still, best solution I've yet seen.

Comment: Good to note you can do this as many times as you want for multiple params. Just use -2, -3 and so on. This trick really helped me out at work today. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

I do something fairly similar, but less verbose:

```
var myUrl = '@Url.Action("Solution","Partner")/' + myjavascriptID;
$.ajax.load(myUrl); // or whatever
```

We can do this because of routing, and ultimately Url.Action with route dictionary parameters translates into a URI that looks like:

```
http://localhost:41215/Partner/Solution?myJavascriptID=7
```

Just a second choice, because as a wise old man once said "It is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities."

Comment: It will break RoutAttribute configuration :(((

Answer (score 13):

You can pass in the variables to any link as shown below...

```
var url = '@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName"))' + '?id = ' + myjavascriptID
```

Answer (score 2):

In the same vein as Brian Mains's answer, you could format your url string instead of replacing -1 with your variable, that is if like me, you judge it is better to read. The following answer assumes that you've modified `String`'s prototype as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673436/2835243):

```
var url = unescape('@Url.Action("download file", "download", new { id = "{0}" })').format(myjavascriptID);
```

The `unescape` call is necessary if you want to decode your `{0}`. I like this alternative, because it makes it easier to have multiple parameters from JS variables. For instance:

```
var url = unescape('@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { id = "{0}", name = "{1}" }))').format(myID, myName);
```

I added `Html.Raw` in my second example in order to avoid having `&amp` in the url string.

Comment: Add your answer with this one and got the perfect answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36981170/453142

Answer (score 1):

You can replace url like code below

```
var jsUrl = '@Url.Action("action", "controller")'; // ## is the token
var getUrl = jsUrl.replace('action', action).replace('controller', controller)  
$("#RenderPartial").load(getUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build the JavaScript code in C# this way:

```
function fun(jsId) {
  var aTag = '<a href="@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { objectId = "xxx01xxx" }).Replace("xxx01xxx", "' + jsId + '"))">LINK</a>';
}
```

Here is the code from the question rewritten using this technique:

```
function name(myjavascriptID) {
  jQuery("#list_d").jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: '@Html.Raw(@URL.Action("download file", "download", new { id = "XXXmyjavascriptIDXXX" }).Replace("XXXmyjavascriptIDXXX", "' + myjavascriptID + '"))', page: 1 });
}
```