# Javascript: string's format is not defined

Tags: javascript

I have following snippet of javascript code:

```
var someValue = 100;
var anotherValue = 555;
alert('someValue is {0} and anotherValue is {1}'.format(someValue, anotherValue));
```

getting following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

what am i missing, here ?

Comment: There is no native string format method in Javascript. See: [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format), [String.Format in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534803/string-format-in-javascript)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`String.format` is not a native `String` extension. It's pretty easy to extend it yourself:

```js
if (!String.prototype.format) {
  String.prototype.format = function(...args) {
    return this.replace(/(\{\d+\})/g, function(a) {
      return args[+(a.substr(1, a.length - 2)) || 0];
    });
  };
}
// usage
console.log("{0} world".format("hello"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

[**Update 2020**]

It's not that fashionable anymore to extend native objects. Although I don't oppose it (if [used carefully](https://javascript.info/native-prototypes#native-prototype-change)) a `format`-function can do exactly the same, or you can use es20xx `template literals` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)).

```js
// no native String extension
const someValue = 100;
const otherValue = 555;
const format = (str2Format, ...args) => 
  str2Format.replace(/(\{\d+\})/g, a => args[+(a.substr(1, a.length - 2)) || 0] );
console.log(format("someValue = {0}, otherValue = {1}", someValue, otherValue));

// template literal
console.log(`someValue = ${someValue}, otherValue = ${otherValue}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
String.format = function() {
            var s = arguments[0];
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i += 1) {
                var reg = new RegExp('\\{' + i + '\\}', 'gm');
                s = s.replace(reg, arguments[i + 1]);
            }
            return s;
        };


var strTempleate = String.format('hello {0}', 'Ortal');
```