# TypeError: String.format is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, string, typescript, jasmine

I have this service in angular 4, for which I'm trying to write some unit tests.

```
@Injectable()
export class IcdLookUpService {
    constructor(private http: CustomHttpService, private urlProviderService: UrlProviderService) {
    }



  getHraIcdLookup(hraId: number): Promise<ApiResponse> {
        let url = ("api/hra/{0}/icdlookup/triggers").format(hraId.toString());
        return this.http.get(this.urlProviderService.buildServiceUrl(url)).toPromise().then((response: any) => {
            let data = response.json();
            return data;
        });
    }
```

}

I wrote a unit test to test this service:

```
    it('should be OK when returning no data', () => {
        let response = new Response(new ResponseOptions({ status: 200, body: {} }));
        backend.connections.subscribe((c: MockConnection) => c.mockRespond(response));
        icdLookUpService.getHraIcdLookup(0)
            .then((data: any) => {
                expect(data).toBeDefined();
            });
    });
```

But I'm getting the error

```
IcdLookUpService Test
getHraIcdLookup(hraId: number)
  × should be OK when returning no data
    HeadlessChrome 71.0.3578 (Windows 10.0.0)
  TypeError: "api/hra/{0}/icdlookup/triggers".format is not a function
      at IcdLookUpService.getHraIcdLookup (webpack:///src/app/hra-form/shared/services/icd-look-up.service.ts:20:53 <- config/spec-bundle.js:134003:9174)
```

Please help

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have `String.format`. You can use a template literal: `let url = \`api/hra/${hraId}/icdlookup/triggers\`;` (first google result for the error message is the below dupe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: string's format is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227119/javascript-strings-format-is-not-defined)

Comment: but its working normally for the code, only in unit test it is giving error

Comment: Did you write your own `String.prototype.format` or use a library that does that?

Comment: No, I've not used neither lib nor my own String.prototype.format

Comment: Can you show working code that calls `.format` on a String? Because again, JS doesn't have that.

Comment: I'm just calling the same service from another part of code, and it's working fine

Comment: Look. The error message is clear enough. Paste `"hello".format` in a browser console and you will get `undefined`. I don't know what else to tell you. If you think it works fine, you are simply mistaken, period.

Comment: Can it be bcoz I'm using angular 4 framework and typescript?

Comment: I don't think so. Can you add a `console.log()` right before the `.format()` call and make sure it's called outside the unit test?

Comment: Sorry didn't understood you. What should I write in console.log?

Comment: Whatever you like: `console.log("about to call String.format");`